# Variadic template argument deduction fails when passing initializer lists

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, variadic-templates, initializer-list

`Bar` holds a `std::vector` of `std::pair`s of `std::array`s of `FooValueAdaptor`s.
`FooValueAdaptor` implicitly converts `int` to `bool` to `FooValue`, which makes little sense in this contrived example, but perfect sense in my application.
I implemented a convenience function `Bar::addEntries` for adding multiple entries at once, but calling it with more than two arguments fails to compile using GCC 4.8.0. See the error messages below.

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

enum class FooValue {
    A,
    B,
    C
};

class FooValueAdaptor {
public:
    FooValueAdaptor(bool value)
        : m_value(static_cast<FooValue>(value)) {
    }

    FooValueAdaptor(int value)
        : m_value(static_cast<FooValue>(static_cast<bool>(value))) {
    }

    FooValueAdaptor(FooValue value)
        : m_value(value) {
    }

    operator FooValue() {
        return m_value;
    }

    operator bool() {
        return m_value == FooValue::C;
    }

private:
    FooValue m_value;
};

template<std::size_t nFirst, std::size_t nSecond>
class Bar {
public:
    typedef std::array<FooValueAdaptor, nFirst> First;
    typedef std::array<FooValueAdaptor, nSecond> Second;
    typedef std::pair<First, Second> Entry;

    Bar()
        : m_table() {
    }

    void addEntry(First first, Second second) {
        m_table.push_back(std::make_pair(first, second));
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void addEntries() {
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void addEntries(First first, Second second, Args... args) {
        addEntry(first, second);
        addEntries(args...);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Entry> m_table;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Bar<2, 1> b;

    b.addEntry({ 0, 0 }, { 0 });
    b.addEntries(
        { 0, 1 }, { 0 },
        { 1, 0 }, { 0 },
        { 1, 1 }, { 1 }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler error messages:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:74:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘Bar<2ul, 1ul>::addEntries(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
  );
  ^
test.cpp:74:2: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:53:7: note: template<class ... Args> void Bar<nFirst, nSecond>::addEntries() [with Args = {Args ...}; long unsigned int nFirst = 2ul; long unsigned int nSecond = 1ul]
  void addEntries() {
       ^
test.cpp:53:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:74:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 6 provided
  );
  ^
test.cpp:57:7: note: void Bar<nFirst, nSecond>::addEntries(Bar<nFirst, nSecond>::First, Bar<nFirst, nSecond>::Second, Args ...) [with Args = {}; long unsigned int nFirst = 2ul; long unsigned int nSecond = 1ul; Bar<nFirst, nSecond>::First = std::array<FooValueAdaptor, 2ul>; Bar<nFirst, nSecond>::Second = std::array<FooValueAdaptor, 1ul>]
  void addEntries(First first, Second second, Args... args) {
       ^
test.cpp:57:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 6 provided
```

How can I help the compiler's deduction along?

Comment: Why `addEntries()` is a template?

Comment: There simply is no template argument deduction when passing a *braced-init-list*, since such a *braced-init-list* is not actually an expression.

Comment: @Xeo Thanks for pointing that out. This link explains it in great detail: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler explicitly what you need:

```
void addEntries(std::initializer_list<std::pair<First, Second>> il) {
   for( const auto& e : il ) {
      addEntry(e.first,e.second);
   }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
b.addEntry({{ 0, 0 }}, {{ 0 }});
b.addEntries({
    {{{ 0, 1 }}, {{ 0 }}},
    {{{ 1, 0 }}, {{ 0 }}},
    {{{ 1, 1 }}, {{ 1 }}}
});
```

Notice the huge amount of curly brackets, but I think the above is actually the only correct syntax. Fewer brackets are accepted by both GCC 4.8 and Clang 3.2, but Clang gives lots of warnings, the above fixes that. Some people are already [working on a "fix"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3526.html), but that'll take some time.

Comment: I was so eager to try out variadic templates, it never occurred to me to use an `initializer_list` of `pair`. Talk about not seeing the wood for the trees. ;) Thank you.